# RSS feed not displaying image in Mailchimp newsletter from my Wordpress feed

Tags: image, rss, feed, mailchimp

I am using regular Mailchimp tags to create my rss feed but the image is not displaying. 
Looks like the issue is with the CONTENT tag not being CONTENT_FULL tag, in which case it's treated as a description and the image is not displayed.
Anyone has come across this problem or has any solutions to this issue?
Thanks

```
*|INTERESTED:What are you interested in?:Fashion|*
*|FEEDBLOCK:http://url.com/feed|* *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=2]|* 
*|FEEDITEM:SOURCE_TITLE|* 
*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT|*
*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|*
*|END:FEEDITEMS|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|* *|END:INTERESTED|*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Shopify images not showing up on Mailchimp.
The problem was to do with the format of the (cdn-hosted) image urls and was solved here:

[Shopify blog feeding mailchimp campaign doesn't display images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118635/shopify-blog-feeding-mailchimp-campaign-doesnt-display-images)

I don't know if your issue is the same but the solution may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question, but just in case someone else needs the solution-
The featured image can be shown inside the FEEDITEM:CONTENT or the FEEDITEM:IMAGE tags.
If the image doesn't show, you can't fix it from Mailchimp, but you need to alter your RSS feed.
There are actually 2 solutions for this issue:

1. Using the FEEDITEM:IMAGE - according to [Mailchimp RSS Merge Tags page](https://mailchimp.com/help/rss-merge-tags/):

To help ensure that Mailchimp can view your feed's images, you can include medium or type information inside the media:content tag.
Examples:
<media:content url="http://example.com/example.jpg" medium="image">
<media:content url="http://example.com/example.jpg" type="image/jpg">
To add this media:content> tag to your RSS feed you can add the following code to your functions.php file:

```
        /**
     * Featured image to RSS Feed.
     */
    function dn_add_rss_image() {
        global $post;
    
        $output = '';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
            $thumbnail_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
            $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_ID, 'full' ); /** 'full' can be changed to 'medium' or 'thumbnail' */
    
            $output .= '<media:content xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" medium="image" type="image/jpeg"';
            $output .= ' url="'. $thumbnail[0] .'"';
            $output .= ' width="100%"'; /** here you can add styles */
            $output .= ' object-fit="cover"';
            $output .= ' />';
        }
        echo $output;
    }
add_action( 'rss2_item', 'dn_add_rss_image' );
```

2. Using the FEEDITEM:CONTENT tag to display the image inside the content part along with the description and all:

for this method you just need to add the featured image inside the description tag in your RSS feed.
The easiest way for doing so is actually using the plugin [Featured Image In RSS Feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-in-rss-feed/)