# Shopify blog feeding mailchimp campaign doesn't display images

Tags: image, rss, cdn, shopify, mailchimp

I'm setting up a simple Mailchimp campaign for a client which mails the latest blog post on a Shopify website. Mailchimp reads the entries from the site's RSS feed (via feedburner) and displays them in an email template but the blog's images are always broken links.

The images have been uploaded directly to Shopify for the articles and are delivered through it's content delivery network. References appear similar to:

```
<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2222/3333/files/my-image.jpg?1234" />
```

Experimenting directly with the Mailchimp template, I found that including the protocol in the src url correctly retrieved the images:

```
<img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2222/3333/files/my-image.jpg?1234" />
```

But Shopify would not accept these modifications, reverting the urls to their initial, protocol-free format on saving the blog posts.

A workaround was to include an additional forward slash after the protocol, as:

```
<img src="http:///cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2222/3333/files/my-image.jpg?1234" />
```

This was again confirmed to work through experiments on the Mailchimp template.
However, when a blog post with these modified image urls is picked up by Mailchimp from the RRS feed, they appear in the generated email as:

```
<img src="https://d2q0qd5iz04n9u.cloudfront.net/_ssl/proxy.php//" />
```

This final caching stage appears to occur with Mailchimp as the RSS feed presents the images correctly.

Is there any way to configure image references in the blog posts such that they are presented properly in Mailchimp emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same problem, try this with the `https://`

```
https://cdn.shopify.com
```

worked for me.